# MemoryError while plotting large oscilloscope files on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to read large oscilloscope `.trc` files and plot them. Plotting one file works but as soon as I put the script into a loop, trying to plot all files (1 file a loop) I am getting a `MemoryError`.

Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc #external file, same location as script

foldername = 'trc_folder'
folder = os.listdir(foldername)
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for filenumber, i in enumerate(folder):
    trc = path + '/' + foldername + '/' + i

    print('reading trc file ' + str(filenumber))

    datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc(trc)
    srx, sry = pd.Series(datX * 1000), pd.Series(datY * 1000)
    df_oszi = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
    df_oszi.set_index(0, inplace = True)    

    #ERROR APPEARS with xticks argument
    #removing xticks does not help, because then errorpath changes to
    #/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py
    df_oszi.plot(grid = 1,
                 color = 'blue',
                 linewidth = 0.5,
                 figsize = (9,5),
                 legend = False,
                 xticks = np.arange(df_oszi.index[0], df_oszi.index[-1], 1))

    print('plotting file ' + str(filenumber))
    plt.savefig('Plot_' + str(filenumber) + '.png', dpi = 300)
```

The problem seems to be with the external module `readTrc`. It took me quite a while to figure this out because python was throwing errors around `Matplotlib` and `Pandas` rather than `readTrc`, which seems to be an unofficial script for reading `.trc` files. I found it on the net as I was looking for a way to read `.trc` files in python. If you know a better way for reading oscilloscope files, please let me know.

I zipped everything you need to execute the script to this folder: [folder](https://ufile.io/n5szvumm)

(It is quite large `582MB`, because every `.trc` file is about of `200MB` size) Inside you will find the script, a folder with `.trc` files and the external python file (module) `readTrc` which is required for reading `.trc` files. Executing the script should plot the first file but throw a `MemoryError` when plotting/constructing the second, at least on my Ubuntu machine. What confuses me is that I only get this `MemoryError` on **Ubuntu** (18.04), not on **Windows 10**.

I would appreciate help so that I can continue with my project. Please let me know, if you need additional information.

**Edit:**

Single Download for [readTrc.py](https://ufile.io/zuh57ujm)

Single Download for [Script.py](https://ufile.io/f09yzie2)

`print(type(datX))` returns:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

printing `datX` returns an object with **50 million** values:

```
[-0.005 -0.005 -0.005 ...  0.005  0.005  0.005]
```

these are round by the `print()` function and are:

```
-0.004999999906663635
-0.004999999806663634
-0.004999999706663633
-0.004999999606663631
-0.00499999950666363
```

**Edit 2**:

To run the code with the new version of `readTrc` make these changes:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc

foldername = 'trc_folder'
folder = os.listdir(foldername)
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for filenumber, i in enumerate(folder):
    trc = path + '/' + foldername + '/' + i

    print('reading trc file ' + str(filenumber))

    datX, datY, d = readTrc.Trc().open(trc)
    srx, sry = pd.Series(datX * 1000), pd.Series(datY * 1000)
    df_oszi = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
    df_oszi.set_index(0, inplace = True)    

    df_oszi.plot(grid = 1,
                 color = 'blue',
                 linewidth = 0.5,
                 figsize = (9,5),
                 legend = False,
                 xticks = np.arange(df_oszi.index[0], df_oszi.index[-1], 1))

    print('plotting file ' + str(filenumber))
    plt.savefig('Plot_' + str(filenumber) + '.png', dpi = 300)
```

**MemoryError:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/zip_original/Script.py", line 27, in <module>
    xticks = np.arange(df_oszi.index[0], df_oszi.index[-1], 1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 2941, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1804, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 260, in generate
    self._make_plot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 985, in _make_plot
    **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1001, in _plot
    lines = MPLPlot._plot(ax, x, y_values, style=style, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 615, in _plot
    return ax.plot(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1805, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1604, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1891, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1913, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 945, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 649, in recache
    self._xy = np.column_stack(np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)).astype(float)
MemoryError
```

**Edit 3:**

Sampling the dataset seems to reduce the data value. These are examples of the same dataset with `sampling = 1, sampling = 10, sampling = 100`

```
srx, sry = pd.Series(datX[::sampling] * 1000), pd.Series(datY[::sampling] * 1000)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

The reason for this is the extremely short impulse period of Ultra High Frequency waves (UHF). Each impulse can be consisting of only a few data values. If you set down the amount of values taken into account, this results in large data loss. Although this solution makes the code work, it also reduces the data value significantly.

Comment: Could you perhaps also upload only the `readTrc.py` file? I don't really want to download ~600MB for this :-) Apart from this: what's the return of `print(type(datX))`? Is it a `list`, a `numpy.ndarray`, a `dataframe`? Have you tried using [this readTrc module](https://github.com/yetifrisstlama/readTrc)?

Comment: Please find the requested info in the **Edit**-Section

Comment: Regarding the `readTrc module`: It seems that I am using the old version of this file from 2017. I just tried to replace the old with the new one but it seems to need additional effort to make it work. I'll try to run the script with the new version.

Comment: Ok, so if `datX=[1,2,3]` is really a list (unfortunately you did not post the return of `print(type(datX))`), then `print(10*a)` will give you `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,…..]`, i.e. the list, times ten. That's probably not what you want, so try to make it a numpy array first, i.e. `datX=np.array(datX)` and `datY=np.array(datY)` right after the call to `readTrc.readTrc()`

Comment: Sorry, I confused `print()` with `print(type())`. I added it to the **Edit**-Section. It is in fact a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: @Asmus When I run it with the new version, it is the exact same problem. I am getting a `MemoryError` in the second loop. What is interesting is that when I delete the formatting in pandas, so when I just run those lines: `datX, datY, d = readTrc.Trc().open(trc) |
    plt.plot(datX, datY) |
    plt.savefig('Plot_' + str(filenumber) + '.png', dpi = 300)` the script gets the `MemoryError` in the third loop and not in the second.

Comment: Does it help if you close the plot at the end of each loop, e.g. with `plt.close('all')`?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. The exact same `MemoryError` occurs in the second loop

Comment: Did you consider [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824726/a-simple-way-of-freeing-memory-in-python#comment98324787_55824726)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took quite some time but I managed to get the `MemoryError` under control. Not only had I to put `gc.collect()` at the end of each loop but also `plt.close()`. Only then the Errors would stop. Sorry for the confusion. I learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, wow, I couldn't see the wood for the trees, as they say. 
You're attempting to plot *way too many* data points (i.e. `100000002`, i think that's about 4km length of paper printed at 600dpi), which can be resolved either by sampling:

```
sampling=100
srx, sry = pd.Series(datX[::sampling] * 1000), pd.Series(datY[::sampling] * 1000)
```

or by selectively studying specific ranges:

```
srx, sry = pd.Series(datX[0:50000] * 1000), pd.Series(datY[0:50000] * 1000)
```

or a combination of both.

Comment: Thank you for your effort so far. You helped me alot. Although I'm afraid, I cannot implement this solution. Please see the **Edit 3** section.

Comment: I‘m afraid your mixing up *visible features* with *features present*. Whether or not your short Impulses become visible in the plot is dependent on your figure size/ resolution/ zoom. You need to find a way to minimise the amount of data, perhaps via FFT‘ing the signal or by discarding values where e.g. np.abs(y)<=1.